# How to prevent sheet name change in SpreadJS

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet, wijmo

Is there a way to prevent user from changing a sheet's name in SpreadJS. E.g. there is a way to prevent user from reordering sheets using

spread.allowSheetReorder(false);

Is there a similar method for preventing sheet name change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent users from editing the sheet name by setting the tabEditable property of sheet to false. Here is the doc link: http://sphelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/SpreadJSWeb/webframe.html#tabstrip.html

You can also check out the sample implementing it: http://spread.grapecity.com/Demos/JS/SpreadJSExplorerSample/?widget=MultipleSheets&sample=Tab%20strip%20setting